# reverse engineering : Creating UML diagrams from existing PHP5 project

Tags: php, open-source, uml

Is there any open source software that can import a php5 project and generates UML diagrams from it?

I am aware of BOUML but this is not open source.

ArgoUML is open source but apparently do re-engineering only from Java and C.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I have re-enabled Php reverse for Douml after porting to Qt4 but you can try it at: 
sourceforge.net/projects/douml